# Googlesheet dependent drop down list - automate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to figure out how to make a googlesheet drop down list for 2 categories, I've got it to work like intended by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ivh5pm4J5tU) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ku17vgq4Q14) guide, however I'm having issues with adding/removing rows and applying the data validation on them, currently to do this after creating/removing a row I need to go to my data prep, and update the indexes for the modified row - I am looking for a way to automate this somehow, is this possible?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `however I'm having issues with adding/removing rows and applying the data validation on them, currently to do this after creating/removing a row I need to go to my data prep, and update the indexes for the modified row - I am looking for a way to automate this somehow, is this possible?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? And also, can you provide your current script and the detail of your current issue of your script?

Comment: What does your sheet look like and how do you wish it to work?

Comment: I've made an example sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ti6jy25TtbA_mR9VkkBL1cfG4XNzicWrsfQB_KnVvzA/edit?usp=sharing

Basically if i want to add or remove lines from 'Main' sheet, I would need to go to my dataset and modify the DATA PREP manually for each edit, I am looking for a dynamic way to let me add/remove lines without manually changing data sets

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed your replying. I apologize for this. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- There are 2 Spreadsheets of `Main` and `Dataset`.
- The columns "A" and "B" of `Main` sheet have the data validation rules.
- The cells "B2:D" are the values of data validation rules.
- When the dropdown list of the column "A" is changed, you want to set the dropdown list corresponding to the value of column "A".
- When the new row is added or a row is deleted at `Main`, you want to automatically set the data validation rules.

In this case, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

When you want to run this script, please change the column "A" of `Main` sheet. Or, please add or delete rows of `Main`. By this, the script is run and checks the columns "A" and "B" of `Main`, and then, the script sets the data validation rules to the columns "A" and "B".

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const {range, source} = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Main" || ![1, 2].includes(range.columnStart) || range.rowStart == 1) return;
  const dataset = source.getSheetByName('Dataset');
  const values = dataset.getRange("B2:D7").getValues();
  const d1 = values[0];
  const d2 = values[0].map((_, c) => values.map(r => r[c]));
  const obj = d2.reduce((o, [h, ...v]) => (o[h] = v.filter(String), o), {});
  const vrange = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const v = vrange.getValues();
  const dataValidations = vrange.getDataValidations().map(([a, b], i) => [a || SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(d1).build(), a ? SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(obj[v[i][0]] || []).build() : (b || SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList([]).build())]);
  vrange.setDataValidations(dataValidations);
}
```

#### Note:

- When you directly run this script, an error like `Cannot destructure property 'range' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs. Please be careful about this. In this case, please edit the cells of the columns "A" and "B" of `Main` sheet. By this, the script is run.

#### References:

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [getDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidations)
- [setDataValidations(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)

#### Edit By Cooper:

> If you want to work through this and the data links in the question are no longer valid you will want this data.

- Sheet Name: `Dataset`

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | Fruit | Drinks | Meat |
| 3 | Apple | Water | Beef |
| 4 | Orange | Juice | Pultry |
| 5 | Banana | Tea | Ham |
| 6 | Pear | Coffee |  |
| 7 | Mango |  |  |

- Sheet Name: `Main`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Category | Sub-Category |
| Meat |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Fruit |  |
|  |  |
|  |  |
| Drinks |  |

> It will be especially helpful when you are working through the datavalidations line which is pretty complex.  If you don't know what to enter the first time through because there won't be any data validations at first. So just type anything in column one of the main and it will start.

Comment: This is another example of using reduce that I'm currently studying and I'm curious how does using the thisArg `o` in v.filter(String), o) help you?

Comment: Also is the underscore here `values[0].map((_, c)` is that an actual legal javascript assignment or is that just saying that you are not using that variable and you just want the index?

Comment: I really appreciate these examples because I like to take them and work out the examples because it helps to build my intuition in using these methods.  Most of time I have no idea what I'm going to do until I start and having a good understanding about how these methods work together is vital to producing good code in just a few lines.  I also  like your use of destructuring like here the second argument `d2.reduce((o, [h, ...v])` that's pretty cool.  It kind of turns one argument into two.

Comment: I finally came to realize recently what this structure does `values[0].map((_, c) => values.map(r => r[c]));`.  It returns an entire column with each iteration of the first map which is very cool is so little code.  Any way thanks for these examples.  I really do appreciate having access to them.  I'd be more than happy to send donations occasionally.